# Get prime factors of a given number using Java

Tags: java, primes, factors

I'm trying to get the prime factors of a given number using java.I was able to write following code.It's returning 2,5,10 for the prime factors of 100 while 10 is not a prime number and also it's returning 2,4,11 for the prime factors of 88 wile 4 is not a prime number.Can any one please explain what is the reason and how to fix it?.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class PrimeFactors {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random randomGenarator = new Random();
    int number = randomGenarator.nextInt(150);
    System.out.println("Prime factors of :" + number);
    findPrimeFactors(number);

}

private static void findPrimeFactors(int i) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int n = 2; n <= i; n++) {
        if (i % n == 0) {
            list.add(n);
            i /= n;

        }
    }
    for (int n : list) {
        System.out.println(n);
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't testing for multiple identical factors in your original number.  E.g. when testing `88`, you find a `2`, but you miss the other `2`s.  (The number is now `44`.)  Then you skip to `3` and don't find it.  Then you find `4`, because `4` is a factor of `44`.

You need to keep testing a factor until you no longer find it.  Replace the `if` with `while`:

```
while (i % n == 0) {
    list.add(n);
    i /= n;
}
```

This way you'll find all `2`s in the factor before anything else.  Then when you get to other composite numbers such as `4` to test, you won't find them.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.It's really helped me to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong .
you need to remove all factors of a prime number before moving on .

for example (pseudo-code)

```
 if i=100 ,
 continue dividing it by 2 until it is non-divisible 
 i=100/2 =50 , 
 then i=50/2 =25 then stop,
 then look for next prime.
```

Hope it helps.